# search for "servers" and shortist path

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can't come up with a solution for this problem.
I have list of components(servers):
2 - 8
8 - 3
3 - 9
.....
so this mean that theese servers are linked and you can visit all servers starting from any other - all are linked through other servers.
The question is how to find out which one/ones servers has the shortest way(step count) to visit all others. Each link is considered as 1 step.
Example:
1 - 2
2 - 7
2 - 8
2 - 9
2 - 3
3 - 4
4 - 5
4 - 6
 
Answer: server number 3 needs 2 steps max to visit all other servers.
Which is the best solution for this? Which data structure to choose for saving/reading data from file where  they are listed as in example?

P.S This task will be developed in C++

Comment: I don't understand your question, but it sounds like you're using - or should be using - a graph.

Comment: Tried to explain as easy as I could. Graph could be the right solutions. Any other ideas/solutions. How to organize step counting for each object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is what is called the center of the graph.  Your algorithm text probably discusses it along with all pairs shortest path algorithms (Floyd-Warshall and Johnson's algorithm).  [Here](http://www.graph-magics.com/articles/center.php) is a brief discussion

Comment: +1, although, I'd go with Prim's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) instead, calculating length of each arm on the way, and the center is midpoint of longest branch (sum of two longest arms from arbitrary root) - the steps are

1. Choose arbitrary root, apply simplified Prim's algorithm to find minimum spanning tree (calculate length of each of arm = distance from arbitrary root, on the go)
2. Choose the two longest arms from arbitrary root, add their lengths, and get the mid-point. This is the center.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely want to represent this data as a graph. Specifically you want a [distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix).

You can fill this matrix with the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

Basically for a fixed number of servers, N, do (in not quite code):

```
int dist[N][N];
fill(dist, N + 1);

for (i = [0,N)) dist[i][i] = 0;

foreach (edge e) dist[e.first][e.second] = dist[e.second][e.first] = 1

for (k = [0,N))
for (j = [0,N))
for (i = [0,N))
    dist[j][i] = min(dist[j][i], dist[j][k] + dist[k][i])
```

Then `dist[i][j]` holds the distance from server i to server j. With the filled out distance matrix it is trivial to determine the center of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

A basic graph like this would be represented by a two dimensional array. Columns representing each server, rows representing distance to others
your example would be  (initialize to -1 to represent an unreachable state, thanks Chris)

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  0  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
2  1  0  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1
3 -1  1  0  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
4 -1 -1  1  0  1  1 -1 -1 -1
5 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
6 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
7 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
8 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
9 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Then fill in the twos, 
Eg. for column 1 and row 1, put in 2 where the column 2 has a one (disregard 1) i.e. 3 7 8 and 9. So for first column/row

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  0  1  2 -1 -1 -1  2  2  2 
2  1  0  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1
3  2  1  0  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
4 -1 -1  1  0  1  1 -1 -1 -1
5 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
6 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
7  2  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
8  2  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
9  2  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Repeat for three. Look at columns that has the distance 2 (3,7,8,9).
Rinse repeat.

As for file format, value pairs in rows should be fine.

Comment: You would probably want to change most of those zeros to infinity (or some similar symbolic constant), zero tends to be a bad way to represent an infinite distance as it is hard to distinguish from 0 distance.

Comment: @Chris: Generally "Big-M" is the constant of choice.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, -1 should do it.

Comment: Thanks guys this will be the solution!